# javascript MVC pattern best way for updating view

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

I'm making side project with javascript MVC pattern.
I have some confusing things to build mvc.

```js
class View {
  constructor(){
    this.targetEl = document.querySelector('#target');
  }
  bindClickListener(listener) {
    this.targetEl.addEventListener('click', listener);
  }
  highlightSelected(data) {
    this.targetEl.querySelector(`[data-a]=${data}`).classList.add('highlight');
  }
}
class Controller {
  constructor(){
    this.view = new View();
    this.model = new Model();
    view.bindClickListener(() => this.model.setSelected('data'));
    this.model.on('dataChanged', (data) => this.view.highlightSelected(data));
  }
}
```

this is a simple code of my side project.
when the user clicked `target`(which is list of data), model changes selected Data.
And controller listens to data change and call listener to update view.
Then view finds element that has selected data and add `.highlight` class.

Is this a correct way to build mvc pattern?

I'm really confusing because in this way, it will take some time to add `.highlight` class on selected data, but it keeps consistency with model's data.

Another way, view add `.highlight` class when data clicked, it will be much faster. But it will lose consistency with model's data.

Or, render all list again with highlight class.

which is the correct way to build mvc pattern?

Comment: Why not use an MVC framework?

Comment: @0_0 I really like using MVC framework, but i want to study mvc pattern with vanilla js

Comment: What is your understanding of MVC? It sounds like you’re unsure exactly what the MVC pattern is, the problem it is meant to solve, and how it solves it. What you are asking is very broad as it looks like you’re writing some sort of framework from scratch and as such, there isn’t a clear cut “correct” way on how to design or architect your code. Please narrow down your question into something more specific.